# AsyncTask sometimes work and sometimes not

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Trying to implement AsyncTask for the first time. When I launch the app for the first time, it works and the loading message dialog appears (although the spinner not!), but many other times when I launch the activity, the app freezes for seconds (loading in background) with no apparent ProgressDialog or the called activity which means AsyncTask is not working. Here is my code

```
private class PrepareFragments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Cursor>> {

    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<Cursor> cursors;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d("onPre : ", "true");

        pd = new ProgressDialog(CategoryDrugs.this);
        pd.show();
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setProgress(0);
        pd.setMax(100);

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Cursor> doInBackground(Void ... arg) {
        Log.d("doInBG : ", "true");

        // my custom code here

    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        pd.incrementProgressBy(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Cursor> cursor) {
        Log.d("onPost : ", "true");

        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Where do you start your aync task

Comment: inside onCreate() .... here is the code " new PrepareFragments().execute(); "

Comment: Did you close your database in `doInBackgournd` method?

Comment: yes, still the same result

Comment: try moving it in onresume

Comment: @Bialy don't update the UI from an asynctask.  You need to use runonuithread.

Answer (score 0):

If your doInBackground executes very fast it may possible that dialog will not display or just blink.
+Call Show at last

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(CategoryDrugs.this);
pd.setMessage("Loading...");
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
pd.setProgress(0);
pd.setMax(100);
pd.show();
```

Comment: The problem is not with the dialog at all. The parent activity takes long time before displaying the target activity.

Comment: Please check if you are doing a lot things in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Try using executor

```
new PrepareFragments().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```